# Reproducing ‘Acquisition Overview’ using the API

Tags: google-analytics

I’ve found the recent addition of ‘Acquisition Overview’ in Google Analytics really helpful, though I can't find a way of reproducing the Top Channels breakdown via the Core Reporting API Version v3.

Is it possible using Core Reporting yet? Or should I be using the Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API for this instead?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sohostu, *Acquisition* reports use different channel groupings than MCF reports (see your admin section). And unfortunately, **neither can be accessed via API** (though MCF API provides the standard grouping, which is in most cases useless :-).

**So you are restricted to using the web interface -- and there are some limitations as well, you can't go back further than July 2013 as far as I can remember.**

[image]